# Use a Zener diode to turn on a transistor?

Tags: charger, cellphone

I am building a circuit that charges a mobile phone.

I am using the IC Chip MP1583DN that has been configured to give a nice 5.30v out.

i want to add protection so only a maximum Vout voltage  does not exceed 5.40v.

The IC Chip has a pin called EN, if this pin is pulled low it will shut the chip down.

i was thinking i could use a zener diode connected to theVout  5.30v and when voltage goes near 5.40v the zener diode turns on a transistor. That transistor connects ground to EN pin of the IC Chip and turn the chip off and save the mobile phone from any damage

would this work ? if so what value zener or transistor would be best to use ?

Comment: You could do that but once the chip was disabled the transistor would go off and the chip would go on etc etc -> an oscillator.

Comment: You want to know what zener and transistor to use, but have you considered other options? For example, a simple comparator with open-collector output and voltage divider on the inputs to allow it to switch at 5.35- 5.4V? Have you considered the effects of temperature on this circuit performance? Maybe 5.3 is not ideal -i'd aim for 5.2 or 5.15 if you can.

Comment: @ClaudioAviChami the transistor could trigger a latch, which is only reset on power off/on, and a "fault" LED could be added to show when the latch was on (and output power to phone is off)

Comment: Thank you for your reply. i am trying to keep it really simple and small as i dont have much room left on my pcb board im designing.could i add a capacitor on the transistor to keep it on for say 5 seconds. that way the mobile phone would charge and stop charging every 5 seconds alerting you something is wrong. i do like the idea of a latch that resets on power on/off

Comment: you can also activate a series transistor that cuts the charger voltage from the battery

Comment: This is actually a bad idea, AND you will never get satisfaction with a zener because the precision required is too high. You will need a precision reference. Note that (5.4-5.3)/5.3 = 1.9%. Any tiny excursion over 5.4 will latch the whole affair off until power is removed. That is why I say that in practice this is not a good idea.

Comment: This idea also has a logical hole: If the IC is functioning correctly, more than likely there should not be an over-voltage. So when there is an over-voltage, would the IC respond correctly to the EN pin?

Comment: i connected a 5.7v zener from 5.30v out to a 33R resistor to a transistor. as i increase the output voltage ( creat an overvoltage condition) from 5.30v the transistor starts to turn on and output stops at 5.60v. so if anything goes wrong and the output changes for some reason  the zener will stop the output from going over 6v. this is not perfect. i just want to add some safety as mobiles these days are expensive and i think it would be foolish to not add any protection.

Comment: @MixBag, you initially said you wanted to have a maximum of 5.4. The crux of my comment is that if you have an operating voltage of 5.3, and, at 5.4V, you latch off, well, that is not a good system design, because you are bound to have transient excursions above 5.4.  But 5.6 is a completely different situation, because now you have 300 mV of headroom instead of 100. Nonetheless, I recommend you look into something like a TL431 instead of a Zener. Have a nice day.

Comment: Also, Zener diodes and transistors have a temperature coefficient that you should be aware of. It is possible that the turn on voltage will vary somewhat with temperature.